# Как добавить новый элемент в существующий массив

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект `{1: 'test1', 2: 'test2', 3: 'test3', 4: 'test4'}`.
Как я могу добавить в этот объект новый элемент типа `5:test5`, чтобы получилось `{1: 'test1', 2: 'test2', 3: 'test3', 4: 'test4', 5:test5}` и так условно до 100 элементов подобных. Пытался делать через Object.assign но вставал на том, что копируется по буквам типа

`{1:t 2:e 3:s...}`. У меня вопрос в том как хранить индексы для добавления в объект, у него же нет `.length`, чтобы от него считать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {1: 'test1', 2: 'test2', 3: 'test3', 4: 'test4'};
const newIndex = Object.keys(obj).length + 1;
obj[newIndex] = 'test' + newIndex;
console.log(obj);
```